# CloudFront -- Always a Miss

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-cloudfront

We are using CloudFront as a CDN.  The majority of our objects are caching correctly.  For example,

```
https://static-d8.raystedman.org/theme/css/font-lato.css
```

This returns a Hit from CloudFront as you would expect.

We found that other objects always result in a "Miss from cloudfront" -- even with multiple requests to ensure the cache is loaded.  For example,

```
[rsm@ray08 ~]$ h https://static-d8.raystedman.org/sites/default/files/css/css_U0-kHZ4VMcN4EKChPMkCrxU_94TFasPMQsBz33LXPAc.css
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Content-Type] => text/css
    [Content-Length] => 212893
    [Connection] => close
    [Server] => nginx
    [Date] => Mon, 20 Dec 2021 15:02:21 GMT
    [Last-Modified] => Thu, 25 Nov 2021 11:07:28 GMT
    [Cache-Control] => public, s-maxage=31104000, max-age=31104000
    [Expires] => Mon, 03 Jan 2022 15:02:21 GMT
    [ETag] => "619f6e70-33f9d"
    [X-Powered-By] => PleskLin
    [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
    [X-Cache] => Miss from cloudfront
    [Via] => 1.1 7b00c3fd9220034414107b03e53b1b8f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    [X-Amz-Cf-Pop] => SFO5-P2
    [X-Amz-Cf-Id] => 0Mu6SkFY50W5MxfeuzhO0a-hhbDgcQqpYVaRZoT0HbWwfJQ6L5e02Q==
)
```

This Miss results in CloudFront accessing the origin with (which is logged at the origin):

```
[rsm@ray08 ~]$ h https://static-d8-origin.raystedman.org/sites/default/files/css/css_U0-kHZ4VMcN4EKChPMkCrxU_94TFasPMQsBz33LXPAc.css
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Server] => nginx
    [Date] => Mon, 20 Dec 2021 15:09:31 GMT
    [Content-Type] => text/css
    [Content-Length] => 212893
    [Last-Modified] => Thu, 25 Nov 2021 11:07:28 GMT
    [Connection] => close
    [Cache-Control] => public, s-maxage=31104000, max-age=31104000
    [Expires] => Mon, 03 Jan 2022 15:09:31 GMT
    [ETag] => "619f6e70-33f9d"
    [X-Powered-By] => PleskLin
    [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
)
```

The Behaviors for these two objects are setup the same way in the Distribution. How can I figure out why the second object is always a CloudFront Miss?

Comment: I think this was fixed when I got to testing it `https://static-d8.raystedman.org/sites/default/files/css/css_U0-kHZ4VMcN4EKChPMkCrxU_94TFasPMQsBz33LXPAc.css` shows `x-cache: Miss from cloudfront` for the first request then `x-cache: Hit from cloudfront` for the second.

Comment: I see a duplicated header in the response.  I don't think it is related, but something is incorrectly adding the header twice: `access-control-allow-origin: *`

Comment: The duplicate header was caused by Apache and Nginx both adding the access-control-allow-origin header.  This is now corrected.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a setting change the the Distribution "TLSv1.2_2021 (recommended)" which caused the Distribution to redeploy.  Now we receive a CloudFront Hit for the second object as expected.  I do not believe the TLS level made any difference.  It is likely the redeploy of the Distribution resolved this issue.